# axe-crawler selenium webdriver chrome error

Tags: node.js, selenium-chromedriver

I am running axe-crawler from the command line using node and getting the following error

*ERROR: Thu Jul 23 2020 11:14:32 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
Error encountered in using Selenium Webdriver:

ERROR: Thu Jul 23 2020 11:14:32 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
[object Object]*

Not really very descriptive. Can anyone point me in the right direction to either be able to get the proper error or even point out where I might be going wrong?

Comment: if left long enough I get a pile of these...
[0723/112518.289:ERROR:dns_config_service_win.cc(793)] DNS config watch failed.

Comment: Have checked path and can fire chrome up from the command line

Comment: The error seems to be in selenium and is uncaught, but the object does not appear to be passed back to axe-crawler. Have tried stepping through but so far the error has been elusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there did not seem to be a way of accessing the errors, I ended up  using a C#/node hybrid, more from a sensible debugging need. I scraped the site with dotnet HtmlAgilityPack and then ran axe-core through node/javascript to produce the json response.